# Is there any way to automate refactoring old style comments to phpDoc format?

Tags: php, automation, refactoring, comments, phpdoc

I'm refactoring a huge amount of code which has all function documented in simple comments like this:

```
//This is foo funtion
function foo($foo)
{
}
```

And my goal is to make it looks like this:

```
  /**
     * This is foo funtion
     * @param $foo - foo param
     * @return mixed
     */
    function foo($foo)
    {
    }
```

Is there any automation tools which can do this? Or it's should be done only manually?

Comment: If you have an IDE like PHPStorm, you better do it manually. If you place the cursor (in a empty line) one line above function definition e.g. `function foo()` and the type `/**` and press enter, the block will be generated and you only have to copy the text from `//foobar` to the new block. Automation can break things or do the wrong stuff.

Comment: @Foobar, So it's better to do it manually? And is there any way in PHPStorm to find all undocumented functions?

Comment: @Foobar You can make an global regex search: Find all functions that are not have `*/` before the definiton line. I will test it now.

Comment: This is not related directly to your literal question, but I personally _remove_ most of those comments when I find them and instead prefer to use type declarations at the PHP level which I find to be self-documenting. That's just an opinion, of course, and depending on your version of PHP and what you are documenting (specifically arrays) you sometimes still need the docblock hints.

Comment: @Chris Haas, in my case, I also use autodoc generators like phpDocumentor. But thanks for advice. I'll take into account this.

Comment: In PHPStrom Global Search you can find function via `function\s*[^( ]+\s*\(` and can add/manipulate comments in the preview window. My negative lookahead regex wont work :\. So i thing using the preview window to updates comments is the best way. Do it file by file or folder by folder and have clean commit state, so you see all made changes in the git tab.

Comment: Global Search is in this case is: Click Right an a folder and then `Find in Files`.  Regex search can be done with click on `.*` on the right. Normlay `double shift` is called global search.

Comment: @Foobar, thanks. I'll try using this solution. If you want, you may answer this question and I'll mark this as answer

Comment: @Geckon01 Nah, im fine. I it was helpfull, nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only way of such refactoring is to create your custom code. It doesn't seem to difficulte to create one, but obviously, it can cause more problems than it will solve. If the project doesn't have a quite inclusive test suite, I think it will be way more safer to make it manually. Also, it will be a great idea to test your automation code before you mess with your real code. This means long time to spend. Nevertheless, the code down below is an idead of how it can be done. Finally, I think implementing typehint instead of PHPDocs will make your app nicer and safer, but of course, your choise.

```
class Refactor
{
    public function handle(string $path)
    {
        $this->refactorFiles($this->listAllFiles($path));
    }

    public function listAllFiles(string $path): array
    {
        $files = [];

        foreach ($this->listFolderContent($path) as $item) {
            $pointer = $path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .  $item;

            if (is_dir($pointer)) {
                $files = [...$files, ...$this->listAllFiles($pointer)];
            } else {
                $files[] = $pointer;
            }
        }

        return $files;
    }

    private function listFolderContent(string $path)
    {
        return array_diff(scandir($path), array_merge(['.', '..']));
    }

    private function refactorFiles(array $files): void
    {
        array_map(fn ($file) => $this->refactorFile($file), $files);
    }

    private function refactorFile(string $file): void
    {
        $content = file($file);
        $newContent = [];

        foreach ($content as $i => $line) {
            if (!str_contains($line, 'function')) {
                $newContent[] = $line;
                continue;
            };

            $firstIndex = $this->indexOfTheLineWhereTheCommentStarts($content, $i);
            $comments = $this->getComment($content, $firstIndex, $i - 1);
            $newContent = [...$newContent, ...$this->buildDocBlock($comments, $line)];
        }

        file_put_contents($file, implode('', $newContent));
    }

    private function indexOfTheLineWhereTheCommentStarts(array $content, int $index)
    {
        $prevIndex = $index - 1;
        $prevLine = $content[$prevIndex];

        while (str_contains($prevLine, '//')) {
            $prevIndex = $prevIndex - 1;
            $prevLine = $content[$prevIndex];
        }

        return $prevIndex;
    }

    private function getComment(array $content, int $firstIndex, int $lastIndex): array
    {
        return array_map(
            fn ($commentLine) => trim(str_replace('//', '', $commentLine)),
            array_slice($content, $firstIndex, $lastIndex - $firstIndex + 1)
        );
    }

    private function buildDocBlock(array $comments, string $line): array
    {
        return array_map(
            fn ($line) => "    $line",
            [
                '/**',
                ...$this->convertCommentLines($comments),
                ' *',
                ...$this->setParameters($line),
                ' * @return mixed',
                ' */'
            ]
        );
    }

    private function convertCommentLines(array $comments): array
    {
        return array_map(fn ($line) => ' * ' . trim(str_replace('//', '', $line)), $comments);
    }

    private function setParameters(string $line): array
    {
        return array_map(
            fn ($param) => ' * @param ' . trim(explode('=', $param)[0]),
            $this->isolateParams($line)
        );
    }

    private function isolateParams(string $line): array
    {
        return explode(',', explode(')', explode('(', $line)[1] ?? '')[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: In conclusion, pretty simular to what Foobar's said but thanks for code. I've made decision to do it manulally, because as you said it's safer. For me, it's first experience in old code refactoring. It's looks like that write clean code from start is much more easer than refactorng old legacy.